Flutter Sccafold not properly showing
Add screen of my app
I am creating an expense tracker app. There is a black button that should show snackbar. It shows but it does not show on The add Screen but on my screen as shown in the picture Home screen of my app. How should I fix this.
The function _saveExpense is pased from addScreen to Keyboard.dart in the widgets folder
this is the link to my github repo (https://github.com/mujtabafrhn2580/expense-tracker-app)
I tried to use Materialbanner istead but it also didn't work

Try to wrap showDialog as...WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {showDialog();});

What?
According to the docs of ScaffoldMessenger:

When the ScaffoldMessenger has nested Scaffold descendants, the ScaffoldMessenger will only present the notification to the root Scaffold of the subtree of Scaffolds.

This means that, regardless of where you call ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar() from, it will move up the tree and display itself on the root Scaffold of your hierarchy.
Solution
The documentation further states...

In order to show notifications for the inner, nested Scaffolds, set a new scope by instantiating a new ScaffoldMessenger in between the levels of nesting.

Your solution would be then to wrap your AddExpenseScreen in a ScaffoldMessenger...
return ScaffoldMessenger(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(...)
    )
  );


... to capture the snackbar within your desired scope.
Note
I haven't tested the solution, and you might need to wrap your SingleChildScrollView with a Scaffold before applying ScaffoldMessenger.
return ScaffoldMessenger(
    child: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(...)
        )
    )
  );


Hope this helps!

I am greatful for your help

I'm glad I could help!
